# How to capture response time excluding images

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

In Our application there are images which are getting downloaded from different site.Our requirement is to capture the response time by ignroing the time taken for downloading the images.

Please suggest me how to achieve this using Loadrunner as well as JMeter.

Regards.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LoadRunner, in your run time settings set a replay filter to not download from the third party domain/host/etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck :

- Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files

> Tell JMeter to parse the HTML file and send HTTP/HTTPS requests for all images, Java applets, JavaScript files, CSSs, etc. referenced in the file. See below for more details.

Also during recording, ensure you exclude embedded resources by using the "Recording" template.

Comment: Hi UBIC,I want exclude only Images NOT other resources like JavaScript,CSS etc.How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Check** "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" box
2. Filter out external domains via "URLs must match" input field (it accepts Perl5-style regular expressions), something like:

   ```
   ^((?!<domain #1>|<domain #2>|<domain #3>).)*$
   ```
3. The best option to configure this (to avoid changing all the HTTP Request Samplers) is [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element, it will apply the configuration to all HTTP Request samplers in scope.

See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1903905-excluding-domains-from-the-load-test) guide for more detailed explanation, use cases and real-life regular expression example.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SmartMeter Recorder](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc--step-2---test-script-recorder) - you can easily limit recorded domains or exclude any requests using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out the requests which has images, css, js, png, and other resources. LoadRunner will not sent/measure those requests.